# Facebook User's permission when using an Application on own website - integrate in PHP rather than Url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a Facebook App using PHP on my website. To use this application on my website the user must login using Facebook authentication.

This app basically lets the user post a default comment on his wall. It works fine using my facebook profile account, but when I asked my friend to use my site he gets the following error - 'Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action thrown in'

The only solution to my problem i found till now is by entering the following URL - `<pre>https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=API_KEY&cancel_url=http://www.magimagi.com&next=http://magimagi.com/login/uploadtopage2.php&fbconnect=1&return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&display=page&req_perms=user_about_me,user_birthday,publish_stream,offline_access</pre>`

I do not want to create a link on my app for the user to click it - instead I want it integrated into the PHP code already on my website.

Here is a sample PHP code I have

```
<pre>

/ Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(   array(
       'scope' => 'publish_stream'
      ));
}
</pre>
```

This is the HTML

```
<pre>
<form id="selectFriend" name="selectFriend" method="post">
<label for="Friend">Friend:</label>
<select id="friend" name="friend">
<?php 
foreach($user_friends['data'] as $f){
echo '<option value="'.$f['id'].'">'.$f['name'] .'</option>';
} 
?>
</select>
<label for="URL">URL:</label>
<input id="link" name="link">
<input id="message" name="message">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this in [Graph Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), it seems that in order to get information from `/me`, you need to pass access token (i  don't remember it being this way before). Using user's id instead if `/me`, works just fine and returns basic information without access token. You could also try passing access token with your current request:

```
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me',array (
'access_token' => $token)
);
```

Comment: Thanks... I replaced $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me'); with your code and got the following error now - Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) 100001205835412_406682472715277 does not resolve to a valid user ID thrown in

Comment: That's a post ID - where are you getting that and why is it being passed as the user ID?

Comment: I don't know - basically the function of the app is to let the user post a default comment when he clicks the link. Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: What Igy tried to say is that the error you posted in comment here is from another graph api request. Can we see where you are querying wall post ID or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

> 'Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action thrown in'
>
> The only solution to my problem i found till now is […]

It looks like you have not occupied yourself much with the basics of apps and authorization up until this point … so please start reading the relevant documentation!

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/